# Using ChatCamp sdk for person to person chatting

Tags: android, chat

**Unable to create 1 to 1 group channel for private chat by following up *Documentation- Group Channel***

Example:-

```
String CHANNEL_NAME = "person to person";
String[] PARTICIPANTS_LIST = {"27", "58"};
boolean IS_DISTINCT = true;

GroupChannel.create(CHANNEL_NAME, PARTICIPANTS_LIST, IS_DISTINCT, new                  GroupChannel.CreateListener() { 
@Override
public void onResult(GroupChannel groupChannel, ChatCampException e) {
if(e == null) {
    // New group channel has been created.
}
}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Please Update the sdk version, Error handling has been added in version 0.1.20, so you will get an error if any parameter you are passing is wrong. Also make sure the participant ids that you are passing exists. If the id does not exists then the group cannot be created, For creating the user with particular id call,

```
ChatCamp.connect(userId, new ChatCamp.ConnectListener() {
            @Override
            public void onConnected(User user, ChatCampException e) {
               // Handle Group creation
            }

        });
```